# Can't create or write a .txt file in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

I'm trying to create and write to a file in C - for whatever reason this code is running successfully however, doesn't create a file. Please find my code below, any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    FILE* fptr;

    fptr = fopen("E:\\SAMPLE FILES\sample.txt", "w+");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter num: ");
    (void)scanf("%d", &num);

    fprintf(fptr, "%d", num);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: `(void)scanf("%d", &num);` Don't ignore return values. Handling return codes is important for error handling and debugging.

Comment: The second backslash is not escaped properly in your filename.

Comment: the path in `fopen` could be the problem , if you share what is `SAMPLE FILES` or try using a hard coded path first then create as required.

Comment: The file is in the root directory of the E: drive. Proving once again that you should never ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow.

As mentioned above, the file path on the E drive is likely to be the problem. You haven't escaped the directory to file properly? Does the actual directory exist? You need to capture the error and that will tell you what is precisely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple problem.

```c
fptr = fopen("E:\\SAMPLE FILES\sample.txt", "w+");
```

This is the problem. As you would know, the `\` is used to define an escape sequence. Because of that, for an actual `\`, you have to put it 2 times, like you did at `E:\\`. The file, instead of creating in `SAMPLE FILES`, is created at the root directory.
Change it to :

```c
fptr = fopen("E:\\SAMPLE FILES\\sample.txt", "w+");
```

And your code should work. I tested it an I got output.
Make sure you have a folder named SAMPLE FILES on E: Or else, `fopen()` returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file for reading or writing, it is best to at least have some sort of error checking and reporting on it. Please see the basic example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int errno ;

int main () {

   FILE * pf;
   int errnum;
   pf = fopen ("e:\\sample files\\sample.txt", "wb");
    
   if (pf == NULL) {
   
      errnum = errno;
      fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
      perror("Error printed by perror");
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errnum ));
   } else {

      printf("Enter num: ");
      (void)scanf("%d", &num);

      fprintf(fptr, "%d", num);
      fclose(fptr);
   
      fclose (pf);
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

At least that way, if you get an error being displayed, you stand a good chance of fixing or dealing with it programmatically.

Answer (score -2):

fptr = fopen("E:\SAMPLE FILES\sample.txt", "w+");

->

fptr = fopen("E:\SAMPLE FILES\sample.txt", "w+");

try

Comment: No, ` \ ` character is used as escape sequence. You need 2 of them to register an actual ` \ ` in the string. In your string, The backslashes are treated as `\s` and `\S`.